# Learning Angular2 TypeScript2: No Directive error with shared class

Tags: angular, ionic2, typescript2.0

I'm a web developer entirely new to Angular2 and TypeScript..well, new to apps in general.

I am trying to set up a shared class that my various objects can get user data from, like SessionID. My problem is that I don't know how to get a constructor that can do HTTP requests.

I'm using Ionic2, so Angular2 and Typescript, all within Visual Code. I started with ionic building me a template, and I don't get errors in Visual Code but get the error below after I run "ionic serve --address 192.168.1.128"

> Uncaught Error: No Directive annotation found on CurrentUser
>       at DirectiveResolver.resolve (http://192.168.1.128:8100/build/main.js:23898:19)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getDirectiveMetadata (http://192.168.1.128:8100/build/main.js:24885:51)
>       at RuntimeCompiler._createCompiledHostTemplate (http://192.168.1.128:8100/build/main.js:39289:51)
>       at http://192.168.1.128:8100/build/main.js:39246:37
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at http://192.168.1.128:8100/build/main.js:39245:45
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (http://192.168.1.128:8100/build/main.js:39236:43)
>       at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://192.168.1.128:8100/build/main.js:39173:37)
>       at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://192.168.1.128:8100/build/main.js:39164:21)

With my minimal understanding, I think the important players in this issue are:

- /src/app/app.compnonent.ts
- /src/app/app.module.ts
- /src/app/service/currentuser.ts
- /tsconfig.json
- /package.json

Those files are below in case I am right.

So how can I get that CurrentUser class constructed with that HTTP object passed into it? What am I doing wrong?

**app.compnonent.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { CurrentUser } from './service/currentUser';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  providers: [CurrentUser]
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage = TabsPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, public _user: CurrentUser, private _navCtrl: NavController) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
      if (!_user.sessionId) {
        _navCtrl.push("login.html");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { CurrentUser } from './service/currentUser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp, CurrentUser],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [CurrentUser]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**currentUser.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class CurrentUser {
  public sessionId: string;
  private local: Storage;

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
    this.local = new Storage();
    if (this.local.getItem("user-profile")) {
      var profile = JSON.parse(this.local.getItem("user-profile"));
      this.sessionId = profile.sessionId;
    } else {
      this.sessionId = null;
    }
  }

  public login(email: string, password: string) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this._http.get("http://example.com/svc/rest.php?action=login&email=" + email + "&password=" + password, options)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
  }
  public create(email: string, password: string, name: string) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this._http.post("http://example.com/svc/rest.php", { action: "user", email: email, password: password, name: name}, options)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "author": "Wade McDaniel",
  "homepage": "http://example.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch",
    "serve:before": "watch",
    "emulate:before": "build",
    "deploy:before": "build",
    "build:before": "build",
    "run:before": "build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.2",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.38",
    "typescript": "2.0.6"
  },
  "description": "example app",
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": []
}
```

Thank you!

**Update**
It turns out that Storage() was invalidating the CurrentUser constructor. See comments below for reason. Thanks silentsod!

Now figuring out how to get at Storage from CurrentUser...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bootstrap `CurrentUser`, bootstrapping is setting up entry components, and with `CurrentUser` being a shared service it is not an entry component.

Here are the docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-entry-component-defined

> Any component that Angular loads imperatively by type is an entry
>   component,
>
> A component loaded declaratively via its selector is not an entry
>   component.
>
> <...>
>
> Most application developers won't need to add components to the
>   entryComponents.

You also asked a question about `Http` being available in your constructor. In your app.module.ts you should do:

```
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";

@NgModule({
<...>
imports: [<...>, HttpModule]
})
```

That will instantiate an Http provider for you to inject around as you please.

Comment: Thanks for offering a solution! I was just guessing at what bootstrap did. so there wasnt' any logic there/

Comment: Done:

TypeError: Illegal constructor
at new CurrentUser (main.js:23081)
at _View_MyApp_Host0.createInternal (MyApp_Host.ngfactory.js:20)
at _View_MyApp_Host0.AppView.create (main.js:80799)
at _View_MyApp_Host0.DebugAppView.create (main.js:81011)
at ComponentFactory.create (main.js:43889)
at ViewContainerRef_.createComponent (main.js:44550)
at IonicApp.ngOnInit (main.js:11319)
at _View_IonicApp_Host0.detectChangesInternal (IonicApp_Host.ngfactory.js:29)
at _View_IonicApp_Host0.AppView.detectChanges (main.js:80946)
at _View_IonicApp_Host0.DebugAppView.detectChanges (main.js:81051)

Comment: Strip out all your other entry components and focus on *only* getting your provider running. Including turning off other components by excluding them.

That solved your initial question, now you have another.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm having such a hard time picking up what you're putting down. I tried addressing the illegal constructor error that occurs 3 times by removing any params on the CurrentUser constructor, but get the same error (with different line numbers). I also tried removing the @Injectable decorator on CurrentUser thinking that might qualify as an entry component, but that didn't fix anything either. There really isn't much to this project yet - it's just "ionic start testapp --v2" Shoudl I try deleting and start again maybe, and just copy CurrentUser into that totally new project?

Comment: I went ahead and started a new app by running "ionic start wadetest --v2", and copied just CurrentUser.ts over to it (along with the changes to get MyApp to reference it). I get the same "illegal constructor" error unless I remove "public _user: CurrentUser" from the MyApp constructor params, and then I get no error. but of course that meas MyApp can't get at CurrentUser and CurrentUser doesn't get instantiated, right?

Comment: For giggles - comment out the body of your CurrentUser constructor `constructor(private _http: Http) {
        //this.local = new Storage();
        //if (this.local.getItem("user-profile")) {
        //    var profile = JSON.parse(this.local.getItem("user-profile"));
        //    this.sessionId = profile.sessionId;
        //} else {
        //    this.sessionId = null;
        //}
    }`

Comment: I ask because Storage identifies as an interface so it may not have an implementation behind it.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! ...except now I can't get to LocalStorage. And when I try to add a second param to the CurrentUser constructor to pass Storage in - "private _local: Storage" - I get the error "Can't resolve all parameters for CurrentUser (Http, ?)" How do I get to LocalStorage now?

Comment: Honestly, you'll have to open another question. Localstorage is accessed directly through the localstorage global variable (iirc, I've used it maybe once), and I don't know if there's a TS canonical Storage implementation.

Given that your other issues are resolved could you mark the answer as accepted?